# repeater databinding , with manipulation of certain data

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is my repeater code, everything is working fine, but I have a problem:

At the end after the `<span class="txsources">Sources: </span>`, I want put the links from the repeater, In the code behind the data source has another field that contains the links, but this fin this field, the sources are written and separated with a `;`  , as : `link1;link2;link3....`

So I've been told to write a function in code behind that do this job...and its `onitemdatabound` in the repeater, how can I do it, and what should bw written in that function? To be able to split them on the `;` and put them as links.

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptArticleContent">
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td width="365" valign="top" align="left" class="bodyContent" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<div>
<h2 class="h2">
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="dsds"> <%#Eval("Title") %></asp:Label>
</h2>
<div class="article-body">
<div class="Article-image">
<%#Eval("Image") %>
</div>
<%#Eval("Description") %>
</div>
<div class="horizontal_dotted_line1" align="right">
<a href="#top">>> Back to top</a></div>
<span class="txsources">Sources: </span><a href="#" target="_blank">Link 1</a> 
| <a href="#" target="_blank">Link 2</a> | <a href="#" target="_blank">Link 3</a>
| <a href="#" target="_blank">Link 4</a> | <a href="#" target="_blank">Link 5</a>
| <a href="#" target="_blank">Link 6</a></div>
</td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create an `<asp:Literal />` control after the `<span class="txsources">Sources: </span>` which would be used to contain the links.

In your code behind, within ItemDataBound, you could do something like the following:

```
Protected Sub rptArticleContent_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptArticleContent.ItemDataBound

    Select Case e.Item.ItemType
        Case ListItemType.Item, ListItemType.AlternatingItem

            Dim Links As String = e.Item.DataItem("Links")
            Dim LinksStr As String() = Links.Split(";")

            Dim Ltl As Literal = e.Item.FindControl("Ltl")
            Dim Inc As Integer = 1
            For Each item As String In LinksStr
                Ltl.Text += String.Format("<a href='{0}'>Link {1}</a>", item, Inc)
                Inc += 1
            Next

    End Select

End Sub
```

C# equivalent code:

```
protected void rptArticleContent_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Item.ItemType) {
        case ListItemType.Item:
        case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:

            string Links = e.Item.DataItem("Links");
            string[] LinksStr = Links.Split(";");

            Literal Ltl = e.Item.FindControl("Ltl");
            int Inc = 1;
            foreach (string item in LinksStr) {
                Ltl.Text += string.Format("<a href='{0}'>Link {1}</a>", item, Inc);
                Inc += 1;
            }


            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: c# would be much better than vb dont u thin :)

Comment: @hassan sleh You're right - I've just added the equivalent C# code for you.