# repeater databinding , with manipulation of certain data on every item binded

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
in a repeater, i want to do a function on every item bounded, example
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptArticleContent"
 OnItemDataBound="rptArticleContent_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td width="365" valign="top" align="left" class="bodyContent" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<div>
<h2 class="h2">
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="dsds"> <%#Eval("Title") %></asp:Label>
</h2>
<div class="article-body">
<div class="Article-image">
<%#Eval("Image") %>
</div>
<%#Eval("Description") %>
</div>
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litArticleSource"  Text='<%#Eval("Source") %>'>
</asp:Literal>
</td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

in code behind i want to do some manipulation on the data inside the Literal

```
 protected void rptArticleContent_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {

            Literal litArticleSource = rptArticleContent.FindControl 
             ("litArticleSource") as Literal;

            string ArticleSourcesR = litArticleSource.Text;
         }
```

ArticleSourcesR  still gives null, somes told me that when catching the controle with rptArticleContent.FindControl i should add something so it would be applied on every item bounded, what is that missing clue.?? what should be added?

Comment: Take a look at the answer to your own previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923871/repeater-databinding-with-manipulation-of-certain-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `rptArticleContent` in the function, rather `e.Item` which will return the current repeater item instance.